# Taking list of tuples as parameters in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I would like to know how to take a list of tuples as a parameter or if there is an easier solution.

I am new to Haskell (only started a week ago) and I made this function to check if the tuple acts as a Pythagorean Triple.

```
pyTheorem (a,b,c) = a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 == c ^ 2

let x = pyTheorem (3,4,5)
```

So how would I define a function where it takes a list of tuples and returns the tuples that are Pythagorean Triples? Also, if there is a better way of doing this, please elaborate.

I looked up some similar questions but I couldn't find something that seemed to fit this example.

**Side Note:** I find that some of the examples in LYAH I can't seem to use in the online terminal: https://ghc.io/

So I am using http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_haskell_online.php instead.  Are there any big differences I should be aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think is all you need

```
filterPy : [(Int,Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int,Int)]
filterPy ls = filter pyTheorem ls
```

Real afficionados would also write it 'point free'

```
filterPy = filter pyTheorem
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but how exactly is it filtering?  Since it returns the triples, I'm assuming it filters based on pyTheorem returning true?

Comment: Take a look at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:13

Comment: I see the explanation shows: `filter p xs = [ x | x <- xs, p x]` but how does that translate from the above code?

Comment: that's another way of looking at it. A filter iterates over the input list, runs pyTheorem and throws away each element that evaluates to false

Comment: So how would I express it using the above syntax?

Comment: `[ x | x <- xs, pyTheorem x]`

Comment: You could also write filter directly with recursion : `filter p [] = []; filter p (x:xs) | p x = x : filter p xs | otherwise = filter p xs`. Or rather on several line (if I wasn't in a comment)